# stop a jQuery function

Tags: jquery, function, settimeout

every 5 seconds with setTimeout I'm executing a jQuery function, how can I stop the process by clicking on a div?

my code is:

```
function crono(selection){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'my_page.php', 
        data: {
            my_page: selection.attr('id')
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            selection.html(data);   
        }
    });
}


function repeat(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.toReload').each(function(){
            crono($(this));
        });
        repeat();
    }, 5000);
}

repeat();
```

Comment: On what condition do you want to stop it? Just call `clearTimeout(var)` where `var` is the timer to be cleared.

Comment: Use a named timeout and call `clearTimeout` whenever you want to cancel it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `clearTimeout` https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/window.clearTimeout :

```
var handle = null;

function repeat(){
    handle  = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.toReload').each(function(){
            crono($(this));
        });
        repeat();
    }, 5000);
}
```

and cancel the `setTimeout` by calling :

```
clearTimeout(handle);
```

Comment: fail stop ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

Use flag to do this.

```
var end = false;

function repeat(){
   setTimeout(function() {
      if(!end){ 
          $('.toReload').each(function(){
            crono($(this));
          });
          repeat();
      }     
   }, 5000);
}
...

$('#div').click(function(){
 end = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the timeout ID.

```
var timeoutID = 0;
function repeat(){
     timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.toReload').each(function(){
            crono($(this));
        });
        repeat();
    }, 5000);
}

repeat();

//stop the time out
clearTimeout(timeoutID);
```

Comment: You are redefining the `timeoutID` var as loval var in the function. It will not work

Comment: Sorry, but it is the opposite : the var declaration must be outside the function, and not inside.

Comment: still asleep. 9 am over here lol

Answer (score 0):

Use the `clearTimeout` function

```
var timeout;

function repeat(){
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.toReload').each(function(){
            crono($(this));
        });
        repeat();
    }, 5000);
}
```

and on the div click call the following function

```
function stopAjax(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need clear timeout and ajax request:

```
    var getData = {
    handleTimeout : 0,
    handleAjax,

    crono : function(selection){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET', 
            url: 'my_page.php', 
            data: {
                my_page: selection.attr('id')
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                selection.html(data);   
            }
        });
    },

    repeat: function(){
        this = ob;
        this.handleTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            $('.toReload').each(function(){
                ob.crono($(this));
            });
            repeat();
        }, 5000);
    },

    stopAll: function(){
        clearTimeout(this.handleInterval);
        this.handleAjax.abort();
    }
}

getData.repeat();
getData.stopAll();
```